# shell script Awk find and replace loop

Tags: bash, shell, awk, replace, find

I tried to find and replace certain strings in text file and the replace text contains "/" and sed commond did not work.
then I tried with awk command and it works fine with terminal with fixed variables.
but when I tried to use it with parameters in the loop it dose not work.
I have attached the code that I have write so far. could you please find me a solution.
this works find in terminal
awk '{sub(/input_image/,"https://www.abcd.com/images/XPDDL_R1_20161007.jpg")}1' format2.svg > format2.html

```
x=1
for param in ${paramO[@]}
do
    awk '{sub(/${param}/,"${paramN[x]}")}1' $output_file > temp.txt
    cp -rp temp.txt $output_file
    let x=x+1
done
```

Comment: can you provide a sample input and expected output for better understanding.

Comment: This is horribly inefficient anyway. Read the strings into Awk or `sed` and perform all the replacements in a single script.

Comment: Tangentially, try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance; your script contains several common beginner mistakes which are distracting if not directly responsible for some of the problems you are asking about.

Comment: The immediate problem is that single quotes do not allow the shell variable to be visible to Awk.

Comment: @GauthamSreenivasan solved it with sed -i "s|${param}|${paramN[x]}|g" $output_file
thank you for the support!